# How is the port a part of a packet?

Tags: port, port-forwarding, mpls

Computer A is running a program that initiates a request to Computer B on Port X. Where / how is the port transmitted in the API request?

Answer (score 2):

"Port" in this context means "port on the network device" ie an ethernet interface, not tcp/udp port.